# How to update the GUI using while using .after?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am attempting to create a clicker like game as practice using tkinter. I am very new to tkinter so I apologize if the question is very basic. I have a button set up to add to the number of clicks and I also am trying to set up an autoclicking feature. The problem with my code is that the number of clicks only updates when the button is clicked and not every second as intended. I am getting an error trying to use label1.config(text=str(click)) directly following master.after(1000,autoClick). Is there another way to get the GUI to update every second?

```
from tkinter import *
import time

click = 0


master = Tk()

def onClick():
    global master
    global click
    click += 1
    label1.config(text=str(click))

def autoClick():
    global master
    global click
    click += 1
    master.after(1000,autoClick)
    label1.config(text=str(click))


autoClick()


label1=Label(master, text=str(click))
label1.pack()

clickButton = Button(master, text = "click", command = onClick)
clickButton.pack()

mainloop()

print(click)
```

error message

```
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1476, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))

TclError: invalid command name ".!label"
```

Comment: You are calling the function before `label1` has been created. Move the `autoclick` function just before mainloop()

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to that you call `autoClick()` before creating `label1`.  Just move `autoClick()` before `mainloop()`.

Also, you can combine `onClick()` and `autoClick()` into one function to support auto and manual clicks together as below:

```
from tkinter import *

click = 0

def updateClick(auto=False):
    global click
    click += 1
    label1.config(text=click)
    if auto: label1.after(1000, updateClick, True)

master = Tk()

label1=Label(master, text=click)
label1.pack()

clickButton = Button(master, text="click", command=updateClick)
clickButton.pack()

updateClick(True) # start the auto click task

mainloop()

print(click)
```